slurmdbd: error: cannot find auth plugin for auth/munge
I'm installing slurm Version 23.11
I have an error message when checking the slurmdbd status:
slurmdbd: error: cannot find auth plugin for auth/munge
this is the commands i used for the intalltion/configration:
# after installing dependencies
cd ~/slurmConfDir/slurm-23.11.5
sudo ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc/slurm --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-debug --with-slurmrestd --with-pmix --enable-pam --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system

cd ~/slurmConfDir/slurm-23.11.5/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo mk-build-deps -i debian/control 
debuild -b -uc -us

# enable services: 
sudo systemctl enable slurmctld
sudo systemctl start slurmctld
sudo systemctl enable slurmdbd
sudo systemctl start slurmdbd

# slurmdbd.config: "munge part" 
AuthType=auth/munge 


I have the munge key in:  ~/slurmConfDir/munge.key , also when i looked for the auth_munge.so i found it in  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/slurm/auth_munge.so
can anyone help?
Thanks,

From slurm official doc: Install MUNGE for authentication. Make sure that all nodes in your cluster have the same munge.key. Make sure the MUNGE daemon, munged, is started before you start the Slurm daemons. [1]
Make sure that the munge service is enabled and started.
Please note that munge expects the munge.key file to be in /etc/munge/ , so you will have to override the service and specify its new location with --key-file.
override.conf
[Service]
# clearing variables
EnvironmentFile=
ExecStart=

# re-setting variables
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/munged --key-file ~/slurmConfDir/munge.key

Check also the permission of munge key to be 0600.

Hello, Thank you for your response,
I added the munge.key to /etc/munge/ .. then restarted the service, the munge serves is currently running.. however the sudo systemctl status slurmdbd is still give the same error

Now, assuming that munge is up and running, check your configure flags.
The default for --libdir is EPREFIX/lib and usually is a standard location for libraries.
Add the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/slurm/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH (not sure that is enought, from the source code is not clear where the plugin are expected to be) or  preferably let --prefix and all other locations default.
My current configure override only --libdir=/usr/local/lib64.
